# MAAS 1.8 is missing any obvious way of using the Debian Installer

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I recently updated my MAAS packages so that I am now on 1.8.0+bzr4001-0ubuntu2~trusty1.  I subsequently wanted to add another node to my cluster, only to learn that there is no longer a button on the GUI to choose the Debian or Fast Installer.   The Debian installer is required for my HP Proliants because curtin fails to properly understand the raid array naming convention (https://bugs.launchpad.net/curtin/+bug/1263181).   I can't use vivid because I'm trying to use JuJu for openstack deployment and the charms are non existent.

So the key question is: how can I force the Debian installer, or failing that, downgrade MAAS to a version that allows this?

--Update July 8, 2015
It occurred to me that my rationale for not using Vivid is not accurate.   It's true that I can't use vivid on my juju deployed/bootstrapped nodes, but I should be able to use it on my cluster/region controller.   I'll update this after I try.

Answer (score 1):

I also hit that bug, but it's fixed and about to be pushed to the updates repository. Can you try installing the updated package from -proposed and see if it fixes it for you as well?

Instructions for adding the -proposed repository are here in this bug comment:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/curtin/+bug/1263181/comments/21

Comment: Happy to try, Andreas.   Which package(s) do I update?  

`sudo apt-get install maas{,-dns,-dhcp}/vivid-proposed`

gives me:
> E: Release 'vivid-proposed' for 'maas' was not found
> E: Release 'vivid-proposed' for 'maas-dns' was not found
> E: Release 'vivid-proposed' for 'maas-dhcp' was not found

And the curtin pacakage is not installed on the maas cluster controller.